# Is there any ways to pass parameters in riverpod's provider

Tags: flutter, provider, riverpod

How do I pass a FirebaseAuth user to a StreamProvider in riverpod?

When using  old provider package,
I used to get the user.uid from FirebaseAuth and pass the variable to the StreamProvider, returning the StreamProvider if we could get the user.uid.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FirebaseAuthService authService =
        Provider.of<FirebaseAuthService>(context, listen: false);
    return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: authService.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
        final User loggedInUser = snapshot.data;
        if (loggedInUser != null) {
          final String userId = loggedInUser.userId;
          return MultiProvider(
            providers: <SingleChildWidget>[
              StreamProvider<User>(
                initialData: User.initialData(),
                create: (_) => DB.instance.getLoggedInUserStream(
                  loggedInUserId: userId,
                ),
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [family](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family) feature of Riverpod.

```dart
final user = StreamProvider.family<User, String>((ref, uid) {
  // use uid to get User
  return User;
});
```

Then use the provider:

```dart
useProvider(user(uid));
```

Alternatively, you could [read the value](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/combining_providers) from the user provider directly from your FirebaseAuthService provider.

```dart
final user = StreamProvider<User>((ref) {
  final stream = ref.watch(FirebaseAuthService.stream);
  // get uid from stream data
  return User;
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Use [family](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family/) modifier for passing external values to provider.

```
final userStreamProvider = StreamProvider.family<User, String>((ref, uid) {
  return User(id: uid);
});
```

When using provider, we need to pass the value to `userStreamProvider`

For [flutter_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod) users,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  final user = ref.watch(userStreamProvider(uid));
}
```

For [hooks_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/hooks_riverpod) users,

```
Widget build(BuildContext) {
  final user = useProvider(userStreamProvider(uid));
}
```