# What is the efficient way to pass arguments to a Riverpod provider each time it gets initialized in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am currently trying to create an instance of a widget's state (ChangeNotifier) using a global auto-disposable ChangeNotifierProvider. The notifier instance takes in a few arguments to initialize each time the UI is built from scratch.

Let's assume we have the following simple state (or notifier):

```
class SomeState extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _someValue;

  SomeState({required int initialValue})
    : _someValue = initialValue;

  int get someValue => _someValue;

  set someValue(int someValue) {
    _someValue = someValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I used to use the Provider package before switching to Riverpod, where this could've easily been done like so:

```
class SomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      // Passing 2 into state initializer, which may be
      // obtained from a different state, but not necessarily.
      create: (_) => SomeState(initialValue: 2),
      builder: (context, child) => Consumer<SomeState>(
        builder: (context, state, child) {
          // Will print 2, as it's currently the default value.
          return Text('${state.someValue}');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So with Provider, you can manually call to SomeState constructor with arbitrary arguments when the state is being set up (i.e. provided). However, with Riverpod, it doesn't seem as intuitive to me, mainly because the provider is made to be declared globally:

```
static final someProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose((ref) => SomeState(2));
```

Which would end up being used like so:

```
class SomeWidget extends ConsumerWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final state = ref.watch(someProvider);
    return Text('${state.someValue}');
  }
}
```

However, with this approach I can't pass parameters like I did in the example using Provider. I also don't want to use the `family` modifier because I would need to pass the same parameter each time I read/watch the state, even if it's already created.

If it helps, in my current situation I am trying to pass a function (say `String Function()? func`) into my state on initialization. It's also not feasible to depend on a different provider in this case which would provide such function.

How could I replicate the same functionality in the Provider example, but with Riverpod?

P.S. Apologies if code has syntax errors, as I hand-typed this and don't have an editor with me at the moment. Also, this is my first post so apologies for lack of clarity or format.

Comment: Are you using the accepted answer in your app much? I've just been manually setting the values of the provided class after reading the provider, which kinda seems less awkward. [Using a family](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63905979/3935156) seems popular, but that would cause more providers to be created if a different parameter is passed in, so the situation needs to be right for that one.

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins Using the `family` modifier doesn't make sense to me in these situations. I may use the accepted answer from time to time but it's quite rare. Depending on the circumstance, I either come up with a different reactive design altogether, or create a non-static provider in the instance of the widget using the parameters provided in a constructor. A little bit hacky but definitely works well.

Comment: Is the "non-static provider" using Riverpod or just a plain dart class?

Comment: @BeniaminoBaggins Riverpod providers. You can pass a variable into, say, a widget constructor, and the constructor creates a local private provider, and the provider creates a state using any of the variables you passed through to the widget constructor. You can then pass this provider to child widgets. It's quite anti-pattern for Riverpod standards (as its no longer accessible from anywhere - you have to pass the provider) but as long as you maintain a clean design it works and is one way to solve the issue in this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use provider overrides with the param that you need:

First, let's ensure the `ProviderScope` in the root of the widget-tree.

```dart
// Root
ProviderScope(
  child: MaterialApp(...)
)
```

After, create another one in some widget:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ProviderScope(
    overrides: [
      someProvider.overrideWithProvider(
        ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose((ref) => SomeState(5)),
      ),
    ],
    child: Consumer(
      builder: (context, ref, child) {
        final notifier = ref.watch(someProvider);
        final value = notifier.someValue;
        return Text('$value'); // shows 5 instead of 2
      }
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `family` then you can put value in another way by combining two providers.

```dart
final someValue = StateProvider((ref) => 0);

final someProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose((ref) {
  final value = ref.watch(someValue);
  return SomeState(value);
});

class SomeState extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _someValue;

  SomeState(int initialValue) : _someValue = initialValue;

  int get someValue => _someValue;

  set someValue(int someValue) {
    _someValue = someValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

USAGE:

```dart
// From everywhere you can put new value to your ChangeNotifier.
ref.read(someValue.notifier).state++;
```

But in your case, it's better to use the `family method. It's cleaner and less complicated.

Comment: But the issue still persists, no? My goal is to eliminate some global static parameter such as 0 and use a local arbitrary local one instead as the state is being created. Using `family` has two problems: 1) me needing to store the variable it in the widget and re-use it so that the same provider gets returned each time and 2) It gets messy if I want to use a function as a parameter as I would have to create a wrapper around it that allows equality so that the same provider can be found and returned by Riverpod. Does it make sense? How about using non-static providers inside class instances?